# Angular 8 Route Child is displayed wrong

Tags: angular, routes, nested-routes

I have a app.routing module, where I load different modules.
This modules have their own child routes and so on. 
For example I created this rout with child routes:

```
localhost:4200/usermgmt/create
```

**My problem** is now, when I just type
`localhost:4200/create` directly in the browser I can access the child rout directly and it will displayed on the full screen.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { FullComponent } from './core/navigation/layouts/full/full.component';
import { BlankComponent } from './core/navigation/layouts/blank/blank.component';

export const Approutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: FullComponent,
    children: [

      { path: '', redirectTo: '/auth/login', pathMatch: 'full' },

      {
        path: 'starter',
        loadChildren: () => import('./content/starter/starter.module').then(m => m.StarterModule)
      },

      {
        path: 'usermgmt',
        loadChildren: () => import('./core/usermanagement/usermanagement.module').then(m => m.UsermanagementModule)
      },

      {
        path: 'realassets',
        loadChildren: () => import('./content/privateassets/realassets/realassets.module').then(m => m.RealassetsModule)
      },
    ]

  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: BlankComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'auth',
        loadChildren: () => import('./core/authentication/authentication.module').then(m => m.AuthenticationModule)
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/auth/login'
  }
];
```

**For example now the Module Overview with its ChildRoutes**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { OverviewComponent } from './components/overview/overview.component';
import { RoleGuard } from '../authentication/guards/role.guard';
import { Roles } from '../authentication/models/roles';
import { CreateuserComponent } from './components/createuser/createuser.component';
import { FullComponent } from '../navigation/layouts/full/full.component';


export const UsermanagementRouting: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',    
    children: [
      {
        path: 'overview',
        component: OverviewComponent,
        canActivate: [RoleGuard],
        data: {
          expectedRole: Roles.Admin,
          title: 'Basic Form',
          urls: [{ title: 'Dashboard', url: '/dashboard' }, { title: 'Basic Form' }]
        },
      },
      {
        path: 'create',
        component: CreateuserComponent,
        canActivate: [RoleGuard],
        data: {
          expectedRole: Roles.Admin,
          title: 'Basic Form',
          urls: [{ title: 'Dashboard', url: '/dashboard' }, { title: 'Basic Form' }]
        },
      }         
    ]
  }
];
```

**Problem:**
[image]

How can I catch this behaviour, that I can just type the childrout in the browser?

Thank everyone very much!!

Comment: Can you share a live example on stackblitz?

Answer (score 2):

Just Remove your `UsermanagementModule` from `aap.module Imports`.

I had the same issue and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to guess why your app behaves that way without having the full picture or access to the project. But here is a full example using similar routes that you posted in the question.

Live Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routes-stackblitz-57639625

**Things to consider:**

1. Always order routes from more specific to less. You can find the full explanation [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration)

> The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by
>   design. The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching
>   routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific
>   routes. In the configuration above, routes with a static path are
>   listed first, followed by an empty path route, that matches the
>   default route. The wildcard route comes last because it matches every
>   URL and should be selected only if no other routes are matched first.

2. If helps, instead of adding the Guard to each subgroup of routes (like `UsermanagementRouting`), you could use `canActivateChild` to run the guard on each sub route in the parent route declaration.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
{
    path: '',
    component: FullComponent,
    canActivate: [RoleGuard],
    canActivateChild: [RoleGuard],
    children: [
       // subroutes
```

3. Make sure to import every to each lazy module its routing module (I think the problem is around here)
   e.g

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AuthRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [AuthenticationComponent]
})
export class AuthenticationModule { }
```

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationComponent } from './authentication.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: AuthenticationComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login'
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AuthRoutingModule {}
```